# Trying to break a two-step cipher involving substitution then columnar transposition

Tags: python, cryptography

So I've been working on a python script to try and crack cipher text which has been encrypted using simple substitution, then re-encrypted with columnar transposition. I've decided to iterate through different transposition keys and find the local maxima of the fitness with a substitution key through hillclimbing. However, this doesn't seem to manage to find the plaintext. Any ideas as to how to get this to work?

```
besttext = text
#Split the text into blocks for every keylength
alltextblocks = []
for keylength in range(2, round(len(text) / 2)):
    textblocklist = textblocks(text, keylength)
    alltextblocks.append(textblocklist)

#Iterate through every keylength
for keylength in range(2, len(alltextblocks) + 2):
    print("keylength", keylength)
    highestfit = [-99, -99, -99]
    transpositionkey = [str(i) for i in range(keylength)]
    for i in range(10):
        print("iteration", i)
        random.shuffle(transpositionkey)
        for n_grams in range(2, 5):

                transposition = HillClimbingTransposition(text, transpositionkey,highestfit[n_grams-2],n_grams)
                newtranspositionkey = transposition[1]
                transpositiontext = transposition[0]
                fit = transposition[2]

                if fit > highestfit[n_grams - 2]:
                    highestfit[n_grams - 2] = fit
                    transpositionkey = newtranspositionkey
                    besttext = transpositiontext
    print(besttext)
    print(highestfit)

substitutionkey = list(key)
bestdifference = 999.0
for swap1 in range(26):
  for swap2 in range(swap1-1):
    totaldifference = 0

    newsubstitutionkey = substitutionkey[:]
    a,b = swap1,swap2
    newsubstitutionkey[a],newsubstitutionkey[b] = newsubstitutionkey[b],newsubstitutionkey[a]

    substitution = DecryptSubstitution(text,newsubstitutionkey)
    newfrequencies = LetterFrequencies(substitution)
    
    for i in range(26):
      difference = standardletters[i]-newfrequencies[i]
      if difference < 0:
        difference = difference * -1
      totaldifference += difference
    
    if totaldifference < bestdifference:
      bestdifference = totaldifference
      substitutionkey = newsubstitutionkey
      besttext = substitution
  
return(besttext,substitutionkey,bestdifference)
```

The link to the full repl file is https://replit.com/@creeperthecat/substitution-then-columnar-transposition#main.py

Comment: The transposition does not affect the substitution.  First try to break the substitution purely on letter frequencies.  Then try different transpositions on your better substitution candidates.

Comment: ok yeah that makes sense. I tried doing something like comparing letter frequencies before but I'm not sure about how to compare the frequencies accurately. I think something was mentioned about using an inner product?

Comment: So I could try implementing hill climbing with letter frequencies using the sum of the difference between normal frequencies and the frequencies in the cipher text, and then use fitness in the transposition hill climbing to find the plaintext?

Comment: I've managed to implement this into the code, but it seems to be quite inaccurate